# How can we generate qr code for json object using nodejs?

Tags: json, node.js

Below is an example of converting a text to qr code.

```
var QRCode = require('qrcode');
var express = require('express');
var connect = express();

connect.get('/', function(req, res){
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });

var sometext='hi my name is saurav ghadai';

// QRCode.QRCodeDraw.color.dark = '#d4d4d4';
QRCode.toDataURL(sometext, function (err, url) {
if (err) console.log('error: ' + err)
res.end("<!DOCTYPE html/><html><head><title>node-qrcode</title></head><body><img src='" + url + "'/></body></html>");
  });
});

connect.listen(3030);
console.log('test server started on port 3030');
```

like this how can we create  qr code for a json object ?

Comment: `QRCode.toDataURL(JSON.stringify(obj), ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON Strigify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method to convert your JSON object into text. Then use the text output into your QR generator method